# How to use part of the url as a target in dfp

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

Hi I need some advice on how to use part of the url as a keyvalue/target in dfp. Here is a sample structure of my link

http://www.sample.com/eu/merchandise/fans-like-new/C0A8015AA2F7C

/eu/ does not change, /merchandise/ would change depends on what page you are it can be jobs, car, etc. and would be my keyvalue target.

I need my ads to show if the url has /merchandise/ in it. I have set my key value to /merchandise/

I saw a tutorial online and it was using below. somekey is the keyvalue/target

http://www.yoursite.com/sponsored?skey=somekey

```
.setTargeting("skey", (window.location.search.match(/skey=(\w+)/) || [,''])[1]);
```

But I can’t seem to make it work. I replaced /skey= with /eu/ and /eu but it’s not working

Please help many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.setTargeting("skey", location.pathname.split('/')[2]);
```